# Issue in sending a SOAP request in ApacheHttpClient with SSL

Tags: soap, ssl, apache-httpclient-4.x

I want to send a SOAP request through SSL to SOAP server (Microsoft IIS server). When I test the SOAP request through the soapUI tool with SSL - Keystore configurations it returns response correctly. But Using following code it returns "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request"
I used httpclient-4.2.3 and httpcore-4.2.2.

```
import java.security.KeyStore;    
import org.apache.http.Header;    
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;    
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;    
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;    
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;    
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme;    
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry;    
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;    
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;    
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;    
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicClientConnectionManager;    
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;    
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;    
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;


public final static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        try {

        KeyStore keyStore  = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        FileInputStream instream1 = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\CCDKeyStore\\mykeystore.jks"));
        try {
            keyStore.load(instream1, "1214524".toCharArray());

        } finally {
            try { instream1.close(); } catch (Exception ignore) {}
        }

        SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLSocketFactory(keyStore,"1214524");
        Scheme sch = new Scheme("https", 443, socketFactory);
        SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = httpclient.getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry();
        schemeRegistry.register(sch);

        final HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        DefaultHttpClient lHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicClientConnectionManager(schemeRegistry), httpParams);

        String lUrl = "https://api.demo.server.com/XDS/Service.svc?wsdl";

        StringBuffer lXmlBuffer = new StringBuffer();

        lXmlBuffer.append("<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\" xmlns:a=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing\">\n");
        lXmlBuffer.append("<s:Header>\n");
        lXmlBuffer.append("<a:Action s:mustUnderstand=\"1\">urn:74347:4757:StoredQuery</a:Action>\n");
        lXmlBuffer.append("<a:MessageID>urn:uuid:c6430690-412e-4744-afe1-233e2138f2d2</a:MessageID>\n");
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        lXmlBuffer.append("</Slot>\n");
        lXmlBuffer.append("</AdhocQuery>\n");            
        lXmlBuffer.append("</query:AdhocQueryRequest>\n");
        lXmlBuffer.append("</s:Body>\n");
        lXmlBuffer.append("</s:Envelope>\n");        


        String lXml = lXmlBuffer.toString();


        HttpPost lMethod = new HttpPost(lUrl);
        HttpEntity lEntity = new StringEntity(lXml, "multipart/related", "utf-8");

       lMethod.setHeader("SOAPAction", "urn:74347:4757:StoredQuery");
       System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(lEntity));
       lMethod.setEntity(lEntity);

        HttpResponse lHttpResponse = lHttpClient.execute(lMethod);




        } finally {

            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }
```

Any help on this highly appreciate

Thanks,
Mohan

Comment: Are you sure the SOAP Envelope is well-formed?

Comment: yes when I copy and past the same SOAP request generated by above class in to soapUI it returns the response correctly...

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer...

Here the following line in above code contains content type as "multipart/related". But web service is expected the content type "application/soap+xml" since this is SOAP request. Please refer [w3schools tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/soap/soap_httpbinding.asp) for further information

HttpEntity lEntity = new StringEntity(lXml, "multipart/related", "utf-8");